# WPF. Datagrid. DateTime. Как показывать в таблице только дату?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datetime

есть таблица и данные, которые туда отправляю:

```
var member1 = dataEntities.Jobless;
                var query1 = from mem in member1
                             select new
                             {
                                 mem.Id,
                                 mem.First_name,
                                 mem.Middle_name,
                                 mem.Last_name,
                                 mem.Birthday,
                                 mem.Ident_number,
                                 mem.Employee_workplace_number,
                                 mem.Registration_date,
                                 mem.End_registration_date
                             };
```

Оно мне выводит дату и время, например 20.01.2016 12:00:00 АМ. Как выводить только дату? Много чего перепробовал, ничего не помогает, помогите плиз!

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
mem.Birthday,
```

на

```
mem.Birthday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
```

Или воспользуйтесь [форматированием при связывании в XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584948/format-date-time-in-xaml-in-silverlight).

Comment: пробывал, вообще не находит записи... ошибка какая то

Comment: @Awesome7997 какая ошибка?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов выражению Linq to Entities не удается распознать метод "System.StringToString(System.String)", поэтому его нельзя преобразовать в выражение хранилища.

Comment: @Awesome7997, дайте пожалуйста больше подробностей в Вашем исходном вопросе, как у Вас устроен датагрид и привязка. Если будет время, утром я посмотрю (то, что Вам предложили должно работать). По любому расширение подробностями привлечет к Вашему вопросу дополнительное внимание (он будет в числе активных) и возможно, что еще найдутся желающие Вам помочь.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов да ладно, частично решил проблему... сделал просто ToString() и выводит без времени, правда в западном формате, но думаю это не критично...